# Where to find filterId for the filters set in the google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api

And also setting viewid number in fliterid for the google management api is giving the following error: "User does not have sufficient permissions for this filter"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Filter List API to get the ids of filters of your account: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/filters/list#javascript

Filters are associated to accountId not viewId: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/filters/get